# How to do I align a Button to the bottom of a VBox in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have some buttons inside of a `VBox`. I would like to align the last button to the bottom of the VBox. Is there any way to do this?

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39323876/) but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<VBox fx:id="presetVBox" prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="180.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
    <padding>
        <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Button fx:id="preset1Button" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"
            prefWidth="Infinity" text="Load Preset 1">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10.0"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </Button>
    <Button fx:id="preset2Button" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"
            prefWidth="Infinity" text="Load Preset 2">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10.0"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </Button>
    <Button fx:id="savePresetButton" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"
            prefWidth="500.0" text="Save">
        <!-- This button needs to aligned to the bottom of the VBox -->
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="161.0"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </Button>
</VBox>
```

Comment: @Zephyr I've added a snippet of code. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Wrap the button in another container, such as another `VBox`, set it `VBox.vgrow="always" alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER"` and you should be set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a empty `Region` between the button and the child before the last child. If you set the `VBox.vgrow` property for this node to `ALWAYS`, `VBox` resizes it to occupy the remaining space:

```xml
<VBox fx:id="presetVBox" prefHeight="580.0" prefWidth="180.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
    <padding>
        <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0"/>
    </padding>
    ...
    <Button fx:id="preset2Button" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"
            prefWidth="Infinity" text="Load Preset 2">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10.0"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </Button>
    <Region VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    <Button fx:id="savePresetButton" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"
            prefWidth="500.0" text="Save">
        <!-- This button needs to aligned to the bottom of the VBox -->
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10.0"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </Button>
</VBox>
```

Comment: For tornadofx, you can use `region { vboxConstraints { vGrow = Priority.ALWAYS } }` if declaring programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Button` in another container, such as another `VBox`, set its `Vgrow` and `Alignment` properties appropriately:

```
    <VBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER">
        <Button fx:id="savePresetButton" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"
                prefWidth="500.0" text="Save">
            <!-- This button needs to aligned to the bottom of the VBox -->
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets top="161.0"/>
            </VBox.margin>
        </Button>
    </VBox>
```